# Input email field and submit black dot has been overlapped when I resize the screen

Tags: html, css, overlap, window-resize

I have an email field with a black dot submit button in my header of the website under a black bar. Here when I resize the screen (90%,110%), the email field and black dot submit button have been moved around the layout. Please help with this overlapped CSS stuff.

[My website](http://wristology.mybigcommerce.com/)

Answer (score 0):

```
   .subscribe_form .grid > div{
      float:left;
      position:relative;
      width:/*xxx */
      padding:5px 10px;

   }
```

Comment: Could you please explain what this does and how it fixes the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are positioning these elements using fixed pixel values, seemingly optimized for a certain screen resolution. (On my 1980×1200px screen it overlaps.)

Try floating your container to the right and layout it's contents differently. Also consider using widths as percent to preserve the responsive layout of the rest of your site.

Comment: for resize screen use @media  screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width:960px){}